cant log the stripe payment, ERROR: Converting circular structure to JSON?
Well, I want my payment to be made, a test and of course, it is being confirmed, it should return a log with the payment made, but it is giving an error and I don't know how to resolve it.
the stripe service payment configuration:
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: [{ price: 'price_1PC5bHRuHnjMMxEpI1UEGeJC', quantity: 1 }],
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_intent_data: {
        setup_future_usage: 'on_session',
      },
      customer: 'cus_Q29t0zXFIFRChZ',
      success_url:
        'http://localhost:4000' +
        '/pay/success/checkout/session?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4000' + '/pay/failed/checkout/session',
    });
    
    //console.log(session)
    return session

my service:
  async SuccessSession(Session: any) {

    console.log(Session);
    

  }

my controler:
  @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'payment-succes'})
  async pagamentoPS(@Ctx() contexto: RmqContext, @Payload() Session: any){
    const channel = contexto.getChannelRef()
    const message = contexto.getMessage()
    channel.ack(message)
    return this.reservaService.SuccessSession(Session)
  }

my api gateway controler:
@Get('pay/success/checkout/session')
  paymentSuccess(@Res({ passthrough: true }) res ) {

    return this.authServico.send(
      {
        cmd: 'payment-succes'
      }, res
    )

  }

error that I am receiving instead of a log with payment confirmed:
[Nest] 31  - 05/03/2024, 6:02:02 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON


Well, I solved it in a very simple way, I was using an api gateway as I showed, but I thought quickly and instead of using rabbitmq, I didn't have an AppService, just a Controller for my api gateway, so I created an AppService and put it first it in the appModule Providers module:
@Module({
  imports: [rmqModule.registrarRmq('Nestor_Service', process.env.RABBITMQ_AUTH_QUEUE)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers:  [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

then I redid the SuccessSession method in the appService and used both appService and my clientProxy, but I used appService to use this method:
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService, @Inject('Nestor_Service') private readonly authServico: ClientProxy) {}

  @Get('pay/success/checkout/session')
  paymentSuccess(@Res({ passthrough: true }) res ) {

    return this.appService.SuccessSession(res)

  }

and everything worked normally
